# Pass element using ng-show AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, events, element

HTML

```
<li ng-show="sample($event)" TestLi</li>
```

Javascript

```
$scope.sample = function($event){ //$event is undefined
//do something 
}
```

I've only tried passing the html element using ng-click but is there a way to pass it using ng-show?.

Comment: The `$event` doesn't exist in the ngShow context, why would you need to that variable ?

Comment: what $event are you trying to pass?

Comment: Oh thanks that explains it. 
I have to remove the <li> element after a condition. I wan't to avoid using ids and do something like getElementById.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute ng-show, ng-hide and ng-if usually evaluate expression and not function. You can read about it here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

However, if you really wish to get the target element, you may try writing a very simple directive.

```
<li ng-show="sample($event)" getTarget> TestLi</li>

app.directive("getTarget", function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(element);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: O_O hold on I'm going to try it now.

Comment: Thanks man! I guess the best approach in angular is to create a directive. Helped a lot more than answering the question.

Comment: :)

You can actually bind events on the element within this link function.

Comment: @user3770093 - creating a directive is usually a good idea when you want to make complex ui interactions, but i think for this case it's a total overkill

Comment: @Shivi hi there, I'm not sure but I've searched all day and I can't seem to find a way to pass the $event.  Any hints you may give?

Comment: @user3770093: sp, what exactly is the event that you would like to capture, as in, click, or hover, or focus, or what?

Comment: this may sound weird but I want to use the $event as a parameter like so: ng-show="sample($event)"

Comment: @user3770093: can we continue this discussion over chat? Comment thread would become too long.