# angularjs how to pass element properties to ng-show function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-show

There is one chart in my application like,

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" height="250" width="{{width_chart}}" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-options="options" chart-colors="colors" chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride" chart-click="onClick" ng-show="isChecked()"> </canvas>
```

And in isChecked function  i want to get id of this canvas which is "line" in this case. Then i want to check presence of this ID in one $scpoe.array , and based on presence i want to return true or false to make the chart show/hide.

```
$scope.isChecked = function() {
console.log('i am in isChecked function');
console.log(this);
      // some code
      return true;    
  };
```

My problem is i am not able to get the ID in function by any mean. "this" is also not working. I tried the directive way mentioned in below, but that is also not working.

> [Pass element using ng-show AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32495776/pass-element-using-ng-show-angularjs)

Please help.

Comment: What about `ng-show="isChecked('line')"` ?

Comment: you can pass `line` to that function via a parameter .

Comment: is there only one canvas ?

Comment: I can not pass 'line' to the function because in actually there will be more number of charts and the ID will be generate dynamically.

Comment: @sand then how the id is generated? How the charts are rendered? Please, show more template/controller code. Right now from your code `id="line"` it looks like the `id` is hard-coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the id like the following:

```
<div id="line" ng-click="ShowId($event)" ng-show="isChecked"></div>  

$scope.ShowId = function(event){
    var id = event.target.id;
    if(id == 'line'){
      $scope.isChecked = true;
    }
};
```

Or:

```
<div id="line" ng-click="ShowId($event)" ng-show="isChecked('line')"
```

```
 $scope.isChecked = function(id){ 
        if(id == 'line'){
          return true;
        }else{
          return false;
        }

  }
```

If you are getting that from another `ng-repeat` or some other array just pass it as a `model`.

Comment: Will not work, because 1. i can not pass 'line' as hard code value to function and 2. there is no click going to happen on chart to show/hide.

Comment: @sand if id is not hard coded how are you getting that?

Comment: If you are getting that from another ng-repeat or some other array just pass it as a model

Comment: its good idea. I didn't think in that way. I just try suggested approach.

Comment: @sand did it help?

Comment: Yes it worked . i created the function input dynamically , like i am creating for ID . Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-click="isChecked('line')"`

In angularjs

```
$scope.isChecked = function(id) {
console.log(id);

      // some code
      return true;    
  };
```